# Angular 2 AOT build error (module not found)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build an Angular 2 project for production, but the following error occurs (full output)

```
$ ng build --prod
Hash: 1d8a022611a079fc4d52                                                         Time: 15057ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.6a841d7989dfdd57acf1.bundle.js (polyfills) 249 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.872c1a24be4bf9c1223c.bundle.css (styles) 546 bytes {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.938daa6986147a5346c9.bundle.js (scripts) 723 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} main.353b80e799563ca86907.bundle.js (main) 2.59 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.da282f8d8f035631cde9.bundle.js (vendor) 875 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.40400ad5f16398e09e79.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '<project-root>/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 17:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I have fixed all issues from `ng lint` that are not just style issues. I know that I need to export functions instead of "const lambda" and the other usual AoT things, but I can't find any issues and the error gives no hint of where to look. I have tried with `--verbose` which didn't produce any useful information.

I have read all GitHub issues and SO questions I could find, but none has helped.

EDIT: It seems that it could have to do with using absolute paths in combination with `bareUrl` typescripts compiler options.

Comment: Welcome to the club. The only way at present to track down these errors is to remove things one by one until the error goes away. The last thing you removed will be what is causing the problem.

Comment: @torazaburo I found the breaking commit, and I believe it has something to do with `paths` and/or `baseUrl` in tsconfig. Did you have a similar problem at tracked down the issue to something else?

Comment: There are a million and one things that could cause this. Just as an example, in one case a missing parameter to `ngOnChanges` resulted in an AoT error, with nary a peep from either TsLint or TS. Divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this came down to two `tsconfig.json` issues. First I was mistakenly including some mock files that there used for tests only. Second I was including `typings.d.ts` in the `include` section of `tsconfig.json` which also broke the build.